# Get_the_terms restrict output

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, customization, terms

I have a custom post type Holiday associated with a taxonomy Country.
On my single-holiday.php, I use the taxonomy to display in the title.
For example
Holiday in Spain (Spain being the tax)

Rarely, but it can happen, a holiday can be in 2 taxonomy terms.
Creating a problem for my title display as I use get_the_terms.

Somebody has better solution for me.

My code is as follow

```
$taxonomy = 'country';
            $terms=get_the_terms($post->ID,$taxonomy);


            if($terms) {

               foreach( $terms as $termcountry ) {

            ?>
            <h1>Holiday in <?php echo $termcountry->name;?></h1>}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change you code a bit :

```
$taxonomy = 'country';
$terms=get_the_terms($post->ID,$taxonomy);
if($terms) {
    echo '<h1>Holiday ';
    $total_count = count($terms);
    $country_count = 1;
    foreach( $terms as $termcountry ) {
        if ($country_count = 1){
            echo 'in '.$termcountry->name;
        }else{
            if ($total_count = 2){
                echo ' And '.$termcountry->name;
            }else{
                echo ', '.$termcountry->name;
            }
        }
        $country_count = $country_count + 1 ;
    }
    echo '</h1>';
}
```

This will output in case of one term:

```
<h1>Holiday in Spain</h1>
```

in case of two terms:

```
<h1>Holiday in Spain And Japan</h1>
```

and in case of more then two terms:

```
<h1>Holiday in Spain, Japan, England</h1>
```

hope this helps

Comment: Top notch answer -- thanks very much - works like a charm

Comment: Glad i could help :)